# Javascript validation on hidden field is not working in MVC

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I am trying to validate an Hidden filed in MVC using javascript. I build a star rating feedback I want the validation to failed when the user have not selected a rating. I commented  'ignore: ":hidden' in the jquery.validate.js file but I am still having the same issue

@Html

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10">
  <div style="display:inline-block;" id="rateYo"></div>
     <input type="hidden" name="rating" id="rating_input" />                
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="btnSubmit"</button>
```

Javascript code

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rateYo/2.2.0/jquery.rateyo.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rateYo/2.2.0/jquery.rateyo.min.js"></script>

// Setting the star value
   $(function () {

        $("#rateYo").rateYo({

            onSet: function (rating, rateYoInstance) {
                rating = Math.ceil(rating);
                $('#rating_input').val(rating);
            }
        });
    });

  // Validating when button is clicked

  $(function () {
        $('input[id$=btnSubmit]').click(function (z) {
            var x = document.getElementById("rating_input");               
            if (x.val == 0) {
                alert('Rating is Required');
                z.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: How would a rating ever become `0`? How is the value on the hidden field being set?

Comment: I updated my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use var `x = $('input#rating_input').val()` to get hidden value.

```js
   $(function () {

        $("#rateYo").rateYo({

            onSet: function (rating, rateYoInstance) {
                rating = Math.ceil(rating);
                $('#rating_input').val(rating);
            }
        });
    });

  // Validating when button is clicked

  $(function () {
        $('#btnSubmit').click(function (z) {
            var x = $('input#rating_input').val()
            if (x == 0) {
                alert('Rating is Required');
                z.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10">
  <div style="display:inline-block;" id="rateYo"></div>
     <input type="hidden" name="rating" id="rating_input" value="0"/>                
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="btnSubmit"</button>
Javascript code

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rateYo/2.2.0/jquery.rateyo.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rateYo/2.2.0/jquery.rateyo.min.js"></script>

// Setting the star value
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `getElementById` to get the `rating_input` DOM Node, you have to use the DOM properties of that Node to access the value of the input.

`$("someSelector").val()` is how you would retrieve the value attribute of a jQuery object. `.val()` is a jQuery specific function that is only available when you retrieve DOM elements via jQuery - `$("#rating_input").val()` https://api.jquery.com/val/#val

However, DOM Nodes do not have a `val` attribute. Instead, `input` elements, in particular, have a `value` attribute. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes

So, try `if (x.value === 0)`.

Comment: thanks whl. Added  $(function () {
            $('input[id$=btnSubmit]').click(function (z) {

                var x = $("rating_input").val();

                if (x.value == 0 ) {
                    alert('Rating is Required');
                    z.preventDefault();

                }
            });
        }); still not working